# How to find ember store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to retrieve record from model using store in Ember. I am doing like this

```
var rec = this.store.find(App.Recipient);
console.log(rec);
```

When I am outputting this I am getting this result

```
Class {toString: function, __ember1397122062151_meta: Object, __ember1397122062151: "ember497", _super: undefined, constructor: function…}
```

My purpose is to get all records so that I can send them to the server. Also any views on how to iterate over them in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store.find return a promise so the way to get the records is this:

```
this.store.find('recipient').then(function(recipients){
  recipients.forEach(function(recipient) {
    var zip = recipient.get('zip');
  })
});
```

Comment: It returns  **thisClass {toString: function, __ember1397123284435_meta: Object, __ember1397123284435: "ember437", _super: undefined, constructor: function…}**

Comment: If I am doing like this I am getting result **this.get('store').find('recipient',id).then(function (recipient){
                    console.log(recipient.get('name'));** but I don't want to use ID.

Comment: It returns me a class.

Comment: **this.store.find('recipient').then(function(recipients){
                console.log(recipients.get('zip'));
            });** doing this returns me **undefined**

Comment: that fulfilled promise returns an array. First get an item from the array then get the zip like I did in the updated answer

Comment: What if I have a multiple recipients? How to loop on them here?